# how do i calculate the cost for a airport calculator?

Tags: php, jquery, calculator

Hi I have this form that someone made for me but I need to change it a little and aren't that great in PHP to know how:

http://paste2.org/p/1909588

here is what I need to change it to:

http://jsfiddle.net/QuNRn/

the prices increase by 40% if the time of collection is between 22:00 - 06:00.

As you can see the prices aren't consistent so its a little more difficult, and with that said I am unsure how to change the price if the user has put the order through between 22:00 and 06:00.

Can someone help me?

Comment: "Look at my two massive code snippets and figure out what's wrong" isn't a real question.  You should consider boiling this down to the absolute minimum code possible that still exhibits the issue.

Comment: note I did say I wasn't great in PHP and you blatantly don't know the english language, i mentioned HOW, this positioning myself to ask a question, everyone starts somewhere, I am sure even you did! So maybe you need to learn about professional courtesy before posting your answer or getting a QUESTION closed! I didn't mention the words whats wrong either.

Comment: I was paraphrasing.  Being "not great in PHP" is absolutely not a problem; asking a poorly-framed question is.  The etiquette at SO is to reduce your code down to the bare minimum required to exhibit the issue, and post it as part of your question, along with a comparison of the expected result and obtained result.

Answer (score 1):

Psuedo-code: `if time < 6AM or time > 10PM, price = price*1.4`

It's ***really*** simple. If you can't manage that, you should consider another line of work...